# How to clean Blu Tack?

Tags: cleaning, home, adhesive

I use Blu Tack quite a lot in my day to day work - keeping things in a fixed position while working on them etc... But I have noticed that after a couple of weeks of usage they become quite dirty either with dust or bits picked up from around my desk which have now become trapped in the Blu Tack's grasp.

Does anyone know of anyway to clean these bits out?
It is making the tack slightly less sticky and not working as well as I would like. I don't really want to buy more of the stuff so if anyone knows anything that would be of help - I would appreciate you divulging said information!

---

For people who don't know what Blu Tack is I have put a picture below: (not that you'll be much use if you haven't heard of it)
[image]

It is used as a way of temporarily affixing something to something else, usually posters to a wall and things like that.

Comment: I don't think you really can do anything than buy more blu tack. Blu tack is designed to be adhesive and absorbs dusts, small particles, which will eventually degrade it's performance.

Comment: As an avid user of this product myself, I know from experience you can pick the visible bits out - but once it goes dirty grey or black, it's time to bin it.

Comment: I recommend [Saunders UHU tac](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0000AQODM/), aka White Tac, less than $1 an ounce.  (I read that the original was blue so as to appear less edible to toddlers.)  White will show impurities a little better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It isn't reasonably possible.

It *may* be possible to melt it down, burn the impurities, and remold the glue. But here's what you need to consider:

- **Would it work?** Maybe, maybe not.
- **Is it safe?** Again, maybe, maybe not. Assuming you don't burn yourself, the chemicals may be toxic once melted. (Edit: [It omits CO when exposed to high temperatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-Tack))
- **Even if it works and is safe, is it worth my time?** Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way! Put it in a vinegar like substance (like [Non-brewed condiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-brewed_condiment)) this works very well and can be done over and over again

Comment: What is a "vinegar-like substance"? Just vinegar?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-brewed_condiment is like vinegar, but not vinegar.

Answer (score 0):

To clean bluetack itself. simply wash under running hot water whilst stretching it out repeatedly for 3 min. Then dry out with a towel. By squeezing it inside the towel for a couple of minutes. Then when dry, squeeze and roll and it should become tacky again.

Answer (score 0):

What I do Is I put anti bac in it and then I mix it it and leave in the fridge in a pot for 48hours and then it becomes all shiny.

Answer (score -1):

Scrape the excess off that you can get to with a tool then use eucalyptus oil on a cloth as it breaks down the tack and then simply wipe it off after about 30 seconds

Comment: This sounds like a suggestion about cleaning the thing the blu tack stuck to. The OP is asking about cleaning the blu tack itself to prepare it for subsequent use.